# WPF: Textblock text in Popup goes outside of the main window

Tags: wpf, popup

In my example wpf app I've added one button and one popup to the window. The button is in the  bottom right corner and the popup has set "PlacementTarget" property to it and "Placement" set to top. The popup consists of one very long textblock.

What I expect this popup will behave is not to go outside of the window and therefore automatically set his "HorizontalOffset" to the appropriate value, but the popup behaves against my intentions.

[image]

Here's my xaml file:

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1" x:Name="window" x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <local:Converters x:Key="Converters"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Button x:Name="button" Content="Button" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="75" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
    <Popup Placement="Top" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=button, Mode=OneWay}" IsOpen="True">
        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" Background="White"/>
    </Popup>
</Grid>
```

Do anyone know how to fix it?
I've read that this should be default popup behavior to take care of going out of the boundaries, but not in my case. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This does not apply to the `Popup`, but you can use [`TextBlock.TextTrimming`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.texttrimming.aspx) for *`TextBlock`*. Quote from MSDN: `Gets or sets the text trimming behavior to employ when content overflows the content area.`.

Comment: I've used TextBlock only in this example. In the real case the content of the Popup will be stack panel with some buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set the width of the Popup or Textblock ?

Sorry, I can't write this poor answer as a comment..

Comment: This property must be set to "auto", because of that user is able to zoom in and zoom out the whole content by another button in the original app.

EDIT: I could set it to the width of the button but it's ugly solution when the popup has huge amount of content and need to be wide.

Comment: another stupid answer : have you tried horizontalalignment="right" ?